# Was the molten salt reactor (MSR) at Oak Ridge shut down over weekends?

Tags: nuclear-energy

I keep reading about this amazing claim such as [quoted here](http://www.popsci.com/comment/233411#comment-233411):

> And as it was described in the article, there the passive "walk away"
>   safety system using the freeze plug. This was routinely used in the
>   Oak Ridge MSR experiment, where they would literally shut off the
>   power to the reactor on Friday, letting the fuel pour in to the drain
>   tank, built for maximizing passive cooling, where it would cool and
>   solidify during the weekend. On Monday they would just turn on heaters
>   around the tank, and then pump it back in to the reactor and continue.

Did that really happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That never happened, according to Dick Engel and Syd Ball explaining their involvement with Oak Ridge National Laboratory's thorium molten salt research:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENH-jd6NhRc&t=12m49s

> - This story of closing off the heat exchangers: that never happened, right? You didn't switch it off for the weekend?
> - No.

Comment: A better answer would quote/extract some relevant sentences from that half-hour video; or at least provide a time-stamp to say which part of the video to listen to.

Comment: @ChrisW the `&t=12m49s`in the link is the timestamp (presumably): [this link should also work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENH-jd6NhRc&feature=player_detailpage#t=769)

Comment: @ratchetfreak You're right: my mistake.